# How to query relation oneToMany array of id in typeorm?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Post and Category are the entities. I know how to do query that return object of relation table. But how can I get only the ids of relation table?

```
Post
  id
  title
  content
  categoryId

Category
  id
  name



const query = this.repository
  .createQueryBuilder('category')
  .select(['category.id', 'category.name'])
  .leftJoin('category.posts', 'posts')
  .addSelect(['posts.id'])
  .where('category.id = :id', { id: id })
  .getOne();
```

The result should be

```
Category {
  id: 1,
  name: 'category name',
  posts: [
    {
      id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3
    },
  ],
}
```

How can I do query to get this result?

```
Category {
  id: 1,
  name: 'category name',
  postIds: [1, 2, 3],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 repo.find({ 
       relations: ['categories'], 
       loadRelationIds: true 
     }).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is something built into the TypeORM since this is an "ORM" and any row is "mapped" to an "object"!

You should transform your data to get the desired format you want:

```
queryResults.postIds = queryResults.posts.map((p) => p.id)
```